# How to keep npm / pip / etc packages safe when they are down / deleted

Tags: python, node.js, deployment, npm, pip

It's great to use the easy package installers like NPM, PIP, etc. For our deployment to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk we take advantage of those to download / install the required packages using a requirements.txt file and using the .ebextensions/*.config file. The only thing I hate is that it make me dependent on those projects and the services they are hosted on. If for whatever reason the projects get put offline, the services are (temporarily) down/unreachable (in certain regions), I can't continue my deployments.

What are the best practices to decouple myself from those services, or at least have a fall back plan to continue my work in the scenario that a project is no longer available.

What I mean is:

i.e. requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.7.1
django-ipware==0.1.0
django-uuidfield==0.5.0
djangorestframework==2.4.4
MySQL-python==1.2.5
django-pipeline==1.4.5
futures==2.2.0
unicodecsv==0.9.4
```

i.e. app.config:

```
command: 'yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel'
command: 'npm install -g cssmin'
command: 'npm install -g uglify-js'
```

I hope you can point me to some good articles as I couldn't find them.

Comment: [pip: fast & local installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#fast-local-installs)

Comment: For npm, you can always check in the `node_modules` directory to the revision control system. It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've done the following:

Download Node.JS from the Website
Install yuglify and cssmin using npm and created .tar.gz using 'npm pack'
I've included these 3 zip files in a folder in my deployment.

Then I've created a Bash script to install this manually which is also included in my deployment:

```
#! /bin/bash
# move to .ebextensions
cd deployment
# unzip Node.js + NPM
sudo -s tar -xvzf node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/
# Create symbolic links to their location
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
# install cssmin
sudo npm install -g cssmin-0.4.3.tgz
# install uglify
sudo npm install -g uglify-js-2.4.16.tgz
cd ..
```

And I call this using my .ebextensions/*.config script:

```
container_commands:
    01_enable_rootaccess:
        command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
    05_where_are_we:
        command: echo "We are here" $PWD
    10_bashin:
        command: "bash deployment/install.sh"
    90_collectstatic:
        command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```